# Why can’t I have multiple apt installs at once?

Tags: apt

If I run

```
apt upgrade
```

in one terminal, why can’t I run

```
apt install chromium
```

in another until

```
apt upgrade
```

is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer is locked and will refuse to run when the apt lock is on.

This is to ensure the integrity of the system after an install.  You could run various install processes outside of the system's default `apt` process.  Using other install methods outside of the system's `apt` install won't have the same integrity checks as the normal system install.

The system `apt` install checks the libraries on your system and the repository and ensures the needed dependencies are installed.  If the libraries were changing while it's installing what's necessary, this could affect the integrity.

There are many details of configuration files that are updated and checked during the install, including the actual list of installed programs which changes during the process.

You can specify more than one application for install on the commandline to save time.  An example is the applications for Samba sharing, which can be specified in one `apt` command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install samba cifs-utils
```

You can also run a command to check for the process that is using the `apt` lock so that you will know when one process finishes and you can begin the next.

```
$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

If you use the `watch` command you can see immediately when the other process finishes.

```
$ watch sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Answer (score 0):

because apt locks the cache and package lists to prevent corruption by another program making changes it doesn't know about.

Comment: Is there a way around that?

Comment: no, corruption of the package list is a serious issue. `apt` `dpkg` and any progran that uses them as a backend will not make changes unless they can lock the files